# How to simulate optional fields in an ADT in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, optional-parameters, algebraic-data-types

I have an algebraic data type that's being used all thoughout my program. I've realized that there's a point when I need to annotate all my structures of that type with a simple string.

I would like to not go through tons of code to account for adding a field to my commonly used type. Especially since there's no meaningful value for this annotation until quite far in my program, it seems excessive to refactor a thousand lines of code for a trivial change.

Also, as the type is pretty complex, it seems silly to just duplicate the type and make a slightly different version.

Is this just a weakness of Haskell, or am I missing the right way to handle this? I assume it's the latter, but I can't find anything akin to optional parameters to a type constructor.

Comment: The way I normally avoid this is to not construct the type using the actual constructors, but rather through a function.  Then I could simply add a function `createStructureAnnotated` that takes the additional argument and modify my `createStructure` function that makes the un-annotated version to put in an empty string or whatever.  It doesn't break my thousands of lines of code that I already have, and I can change my data structures more or less as I see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go as far as declaring "a weakness of Haskell" - more like something that's needed to take into account when dealing with ADTs (and not specifically in Haskell).

Each program consists of "entities" and "actions". Your problem is that you need to modify an entity (an ADT in Haskell).

In an OOP language the solution will be straightforward - subclass you type. But if you'll decide to change the signature of a method in an existing class - you'll have no choice but to go through your entire codebase and deal with the damage.

In a functional language, functions are "cheap" - each function is independent from the ADT and refactoring it is often simple. Is that a weakness of OOP languages? No - it's just a tradeoff between ease of modifying existing "actions" (which is easy in functional languages) and ease of modifying "entities" (which is easy in OOP languages).

And in a practical note:

1. Designing an ADT is very important since changing can be very expensive.
2. @bheklilr's advice is priceless - follow it!